# Show Texts in single.php if it's from a specific page

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm working on a site where I'm using one single.php for my posts and custom post types. I have a page which I will call "blog" for the purpose of this question. I want to show some texts just after `the_content();` only in single page of "blog". I have tried different conditionals but none seems to work. Below is a sample code I used

```
<?php the_content(); ?><br>
<?php
if(is_page('blog')) {
  echo "Text to display";
}
?>
```

Comment: did you try with page id ? like this : is_page( 42 );

Comment: Yes I did but it didn't work

Answer (score 1):

You can try by it I think it will works for you:

```
<?php the_content(); ?><br>
<?php
if (is_blog()) {
  echo "Text to display";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use a post meta,Create a [metabox](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/metadata/custom-meta-boxes/) where to save your custom meta
then modify your template to display the meta only if its present

```
if( ! get_post_meta( '1', 'my_custom_meta', true ) ) {
 echo "Text to display";

}
```

Comment: I don't want to use metabox because I plan to add more items. The echoed text is just for the purpose of this question.

Comment: then go with Akshay Shah comment or Chiranjib Dey answer